# What is the meaning of "exactly see assisting"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In Biography English movie *Marie Antoinette (2006)*, There is discussion about American Revolution.

> French Economic Man: The Americans are asking for help in their
>   revolution.
>
> Louis XIV: Well, I can't **exactly see assisting** those who are rejecting
>   their sovereign.
>
> French Economic Man: But it would make a strong statement to England.
>
> Louis XIV: Can our finances take the strain?
>
> French Economic Man: Oh, taxes will be raised slightly. I recommend we
>   help our American brothers and  show the rest of Europe our strength.
>
> Louis XIV: All right, then. Send funds to America.

Comment: "I cannot really envision (myself, us) offering aid to those who are rejecting their king", that is, "I am having some difficulty envisioning (myself, us) offering aid to those who are rejecting their king."    Why should we assist those who would reject their king's right to rule over them?

Comment: This can't be Louis XIV, who died in 1715; it's Louis XVI, who was married to Marie Antoinette and reigned during the American Revolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gerund phrase headed by *assisting* is the object or complement of *see*.

*Can see* in this context is an idiom meaning approximately “regard as desirable” or “regard as feasible”. (In some circumstances it can have the sense “regard as *possible*”, but I don’t think that’s in play here.) It’s typically cast as a negative:

> I can't see assisting those who reject their sovereign = *I don't regard assisting those who reject their sovereign as an appropriate action for France to take.*

But hypothetical and positive uses are not unknown:

> I could see raising taxes a little bit under some circumstances.
>   Telling England where to stick it—now **that** I can see!

*Exactly* is an adverb modifying *see*—basically a ‘hedge’ that takes some of the sting out of what would otherwise be a flat denial:

> I don't *exactly* regard assisting these people as inappropriate (but that’s *pretty close* to how I regard it).

Comment: Is *Louis XIV* saying that "he can't care who don't need help from France"?

Comment: @user60740 No. Louis is a king himself: he naturally disapproves of subjects rebelling against their king.